# How Can I Force Execution to the Catch Block?

Tags: c#, exception

I am wondering can `try..catch` force execution to go into the `catch` and run code in there?

here example code:

```
try {
    if (AnyConditionTrue) {
      // run some code
    }
    else {
      // go catch
    }
} catch (Exception) {
    // run some code here...
}
```

Comment: Exceptions are for handling **exceptional** behavior. They are not meant for control flow.

Comment: You mean like raising an exception in the else statement?  Sure.  It isn't the best way of designing your application but it is possible.  Just do a Throw new Exception("This is a simple exception");

Comment: `throw new Exception("Some Message")`

Comment: You could throw an exception in your else, but you should not use exceptions for control flow.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this would be the right solution to any problem. Could you post some more details on what you are trying to do?

Comment: In the case of using `fetch API`, requests that return status code 4xx do not hit the `catch`, so, testing for the status code and throwing an Exception may be a viable solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Rather than throwing an Exception in the `else`, I would recommend extracting the code from your `catch` into a method and call that from your else

```
try
{
    if (AnyConditionTrue)
    {
        MethodWhenTrue();
    }
    else
    {
        HandleError();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    HandleError();
}
```

Comment: in my opinion, i still prefer `throw new Exception` as there may be some codes below `if...else...` that I don't want to execute them whenever the Error appear

Comment: @Jacky If there is code you don't want to execute when there is an exception, the code should be in the try block. If you don't want it to execute in the else condition, why isn't it in the if?

Comment: Let's see my example https://dotnetfiddle.net/EN1Wd2 I don't want the code to run to the line 18, because my whole function `try...catch...` may contain multiple `if...else...`

Answer (score 46):

```
   try{
      if (AnyConditionTrue){
              //run some code
               }
      else{
              throw new Exception();
          }
   }
   catch(){

      //run some code here...

   }
```

But like Yuck has stated, I wouldn't recommend this.  You should take a step back at your design and what you're looking to accomplish.  There's a better way to do it (i.e. with normal conditional flow, instead of exception handling).

Comment: +1 As it *does* answer the question on how you would go about doing it. For control flow this is bad practice, as you've mentioned. It's rare that you'd need to throw an exception to be caught by the same `try..catch` construct.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you have to throw exception :

```
  try
  {
    throw new Exception("hello");
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {

     //run some code here...
  }
```

Comment: Whilst this isn't technically the best way to do what the OP needs to do, it IS the simple solution to the question asked by the OP.

Answer (score 9):

An effective way to throw an `Exception` and also jump to `Catch` as so:

```
try
{
   throw new Exception("Exception Message");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   // after the throw, you will land here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(conditiontrue)
{

}
else{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you `throw` the exception that you intend to `catch` from within the try, it will be caught in the catch section.

I have to ask you why you would want to do this though? Exception handling is not meant to be a substitute for control flow.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a `finally` block:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

see this

```
try
 {
     doSomething();
 }
catch
 {
     catchSomething();
     throw an error
 } 
finally
 {
     alwaysDoThis();
 }
```

This is different if/when you do this:

```
try
 {
     doSomething(); 
 }
 catch
 {
     catchSomething(); 
     throw an error
 }
  alwaysDoThis();// will not run on error (in the catch) condition
```

the the this last instance, if an error occurs, the catch will execute but NOT the `alwaysDoThis();`.  Of course you can still have multiple `catch` as always.

Comment: The question wants to the code to run only if AnyConditionTrue is false or an exception is thrown.  A finally will run even if AnyConditionTrue is true and no exception is thrown.  You could add an if to check for AnyConditionTrue false, but that will not satisfy AnyConditionTrue is true and an exception is thrown.

Comment: I course if you pull the plug on the power, you have an unknown state of execution.

Comment: @cadrell0 - yes, understood, just adding this example in case that resolves the issue - which is to NOT do flow control in this manner but DO it in the manner described IF it is TRULY an error condition and not simply flow control this may be appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand the difference you're trying to show here. Those two blocks of code do the same thing. Why do you think that in the second example the `alwaysDoThis` will not run if an exception is caught?

Comment: I probably should have been more precise - what I mean here is that if you throw an error in the catch block, the condition exists where in the second example the statement does not run. Adding more precise code :)

Answer (score 1):

As cadrel said, but pass through an Exception to provide more feedback, which will be shown in the innerException:

```
try
{
    if (AnyConditionTrue)
    {
        MethodWhenTrue();
    }
    else
    {
        HandleError(new Exception("AnyCondition is not true"));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HandleError(ex);
}
```

...

```
private void HandleError(Exception ex) {
    throw new ApplicationException("Failure!", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomException: Exception
{
     public CustomException(string message)
        : base(message) { }

}
```

//

```
if(something == anything)
{
   throw new CustomException(" custom text message");
}
```

you can try this

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an exception to force a catch

```
throw new Exception(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you catching an exception? Why not just run the code in your "else" block? If you MUST do it that way, just throw a new exception

```
throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight resurrection, but I wanted to add both a sample (primarily like others) and a use case.

```
public int GetValueNum(string name)
    {
        int _ret = 0;

        try
        {
            Control c = (extendedControls.Single(s => s.ValueName == name) as Control);

            if (c.GetType() == typeof(ExtendedNumericUpDown))
                _ret = (int)((ExtendedNumericUpDown)c).Value;

            else
                throw new Exception();
        }

        catch
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(String.Format("Invalid cast fetching .Value value for {0}.\nExtendedControllerListener.GetValueNum()", name));
        }

        return _ret;
    }
```

In my case, I have custom controls - a handful of controls that use a base Windows.Forms control, but add two bools and a string for tracking, and also automatically get registered to a Singleton `List<T>` so they can be properly fetched without drilling down through control containers (it's a tabbed form).

In this case, I'm creating some methods to easily get values (`.Value, .Text, .Checked, .Enabled`) by a name string.  In the case of `.Value`, not all `Control` objects have it.  If the extended control is not of type `ExtendedNumericUpDown`, it IS an `InvalidCastException` as the method should not be called against that type of control.  This isn't flow, but the prescribed usage of invalid cast.  Since `Control` doesn't naturally have a `.Value` property, Visual Studio won't let me just force an attempt and fail after.